# IOS Notification issue

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am working on Notification and my understanding on this is that IOS notifications like "textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)iTextField" gets posted only when you tap on a text field.

To my strange notice, my code is receiving this notification when I am tapping on "Back" button to go back to my previous view.

What are the possible chances of me getting this notification again. I believe we need not to register for such notifications. I have registered only for keyboard hide/show notifications.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please consider using a more descriptive question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was I was adding my textfield as first responder before server call and then was only removing it when you hit the return button or hit any other text field. That's why it was not getting resigned when back button was pressed. Now I have resigned it soon after server call.

Comment: Glad you worked it out, but how does that differ from the suggestion in my last comment?

Comment: Well, as I understand it, going by your way was not helping me because my textfield was still acting as a responder and after keyboardwillhide method it was always going to textFieldWillRespond even if we place a return statement there.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your question at first, but finally recommended that you just call `resignFirstResponder` since you had a reference to the field.  It's not important.  If it works and someone else can find the answer here, then all's well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question.  See the OP's answer.

Well, the keyboard *will* disappear upon navigation.  It makes sense that the notification is posted in this case.  One way to ignore notifications generated in response to view transitions is to keep track of your view controller's state.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    _transitioningView = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    _transitioningView = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _transitioningView = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _transitioningView = NO;
}
```

Now, in the selector called by your keyboard notification, you can just return if the view is transitioning.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notif {
    if (_transitioningView)
        return;
    // Handle keyboard dismissal.
}
```

Comment: This is not helping. Putting the return statement is not breaking the flow. It is still taking me to textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)iTextField  method :(

Comment: Then I did not understand your question correctly.  Are you saying that `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is called when you navigate away from the field's parent view controller?

Comment: Let me explain it in more detail. When I tap on my text field I am setting that text field as my first responder by self.parentController setFirstResponderView:iTextField].      Now, when I am clicking on back button, there is no way I can resign as first responder for this text field. Which is creating the issue.

Comment: I understand that key board will disappear on navigation but then it again comes up and that is because my text field is still the first responder for this textfield. I have not resigned that.

Comment: Why not maintain a reference to the text field and call `resignFirstResponder`?